# EC2 instance dhcp options when ip is statically set on ENI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-networking

I am just going through dhcp option sets and its mentioned that domain name and name-server are assigned through dhcp options. Now when i set the ip address statically during instance creation, then the ENI wont be running any dhcp. Now as i am typing this i realize that there is something behind the scenes because all other settings are not defined during instance creation so does it mean that our IP is assigned statically through dhcp (like some sort of host binding?).